# What do you do with Pending (Incomplete Transaction)?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, pending

We currently use Paypal until we can figure out why Stripe is not working. If a user does not complete the paypal payment, CiviCRM correctly lists the transaction as Pending (Incomplete Transaction).  Since most users eventually create a new transaction, we are left with a number of Pending (Incomplete Transaction) activities.

I have begun to list those activities as Expired but I then thought Cancelled may be a better fit.  Then I wondered if I should just leave it alone.  What do you all recommend?  What do you do?

Answer (score 1):

We do several things with these. In most cases we filter them out of all reports. If the user creates a new transaction we will leave them as is or delete them. Sometimes we create a special status for these in case they need to be referred to later (maybe the entries are different).

It really comes down to what works best for your internal processes.